# ReferenceError: myData is not defined

Tags: angularjs, json

I am learnig angular js service.Try to execute following code which reads JSON from a json file.

**data.json**

```
 {
   "name": "ishmam",
   "age": "23"
 }
```

**Body of html:**

```
<body ng-app="myAppp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">


<div>
     {{myData.name}}
</div>

    <script>
         var app = angular.module('myAppp', []);
         app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
             $http.get('data.json').then(function (response) {
                 $scope.myData = response.data.records;
                 console.log("sadas"); //this is ok
                 console.log(myData.name); //this is showing error
             });
         });
    </script>

 </body>
```

Getting the following error:

> ```
> ReferenceError: myData is not defined
>   at MyAJ.html:30
>   at processQueue (angular.js:15552)
>   at angular.js:15568
>   at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16820)
>   at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16636)
>   at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16928)
>   at done (angular.js:11266)
>   at completeRequest (angular.js:11464)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11405)
> ```

Why?

Comment: Well, `myData` *is* not defined. There *is* a property `myData` *on* `$scope` though...

Comment: At any rate, there's one final bit of info missing in the post I'd think: what is the `response` object? I'm guessing it's not the object you posted in the snippet above, since your code seems to expect a `records` (array?) property on it?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to log `myData` which doesn't exist.

try this

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response){
    // Will have proper data only if your response has the key 'records'. 
    // Otherwise your $scope.myData will have undefined value
    console.log(response.data) //Check if Key 'records' is present.

    $scope.myData = response.data.records;
    console.log($scope.myData.name);
});
```

Comment: I have done this but the following error is shown:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Edited answer. The above should work unless your response doesn't have the key `records`

Answer (score 0):

myData is not defined..

Use `$scope.myData` to get output.

Comment: I have done this but the following error is shown: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: I have done this but the following error is shown: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: please console  is `$scope.myData` and `response`

Comment: then check `response.data` in console ..I think that is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The error is you are referencing `response.data.records` in the `success` callback of `then`. Your json will be available on `response.data` directly. So what you need to do is just access that like

```
$http.get('data.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data; // just access data, not data.response
            console.log("sadas"); //this is ok
            console.log($scope.myData.name); //you need to access $scope.myData, rather than just myData
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('myAppp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
$scope.myData={};
});
$http.get('data.json').then(function (response) {
$scope.myData = response.data.records;
console.log($scope.myData ); //make sure this is not null/undefined
console.log($scope.myData.name); //if not null this will work
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this i think that's may be work for you

```
myData[0].name
```